# Как работают функции: ord(), eval(), ''.join(...),

Tags: python, golang

Кто может объяснить суть алгоритма? (Алгоритм дешифрации PSI пароля)

Код:

```
import re
import math
import itertools

print ''.join([chr(eval('0x' + found) ^ ord('user@xmpp.jp'[index])) 
for (found, index) in itertools.izip(re.findall('.{4}', '000passwordstring'), itertools.count())])
```

Я в Python почти ничего не понимаю, а переписать на Golang очень хочу, но я не понимаю принципа работы алгоритма и таких методов как `"ord, eval"`. 
Кто может объяснить принцип работы ? (дешифрация паролей). Может кто ещё сможет помочь с реализацией на Golang :)

Comment: Ну уж методы-то точно можно легко из документации питона вычитать

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я напишу нужные вещи в примерах (результат в комментариях):

- метод `.join()`:

  ```
  ''.join(['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'])                   # 'dogcatmouse'
  ```
- функция `chr()`:

  ```
  chr(65)                                            # 'A'
  chr(66)                                            # 'B'
  ```
- функция `ord()`:

  ```
  ord('A')                                           # 65
  ord('B')                                           # 66
  ```
- функция `eval()` (вычислить) и оператор `^` (XOR):

  ```
  eval('2 + 3')                                      # 5
  eval('0x7A ^ 0x23')                                # 0x59 (== 0b01011001 == 89)
  eval('0b01111010 ^ 0b00100011')                    # 0x59 (== 0b01011001 == 89)
  ```
- функция `itertools.izip()`:

  ```
  itertools.izip(['dog', 'cat', 'mouse'], [5, 7])    # (('dog', 5), ('cat', 7))
  ```
- функция `itertools.count()`:

  ```
  itertools.count()                                  # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,...)
  ```
- функция `re.findall()` (`re` - регулярные выражения):

  ```
  re.findall('.{4}', '000passwordstring')            # ['000p', 'assw', 'ords', 'trin']
  ```
- И так, ваша команда `for`:

  ```
  for (found, index) in itertools.izip(re.findall('.{4}', '000passwordstring'), itertools.count())]):
  ```

  представляет собой *цикл* с 4 итерациами:

  1. В первом переходе будет          `found == '000p'` и `index == 0`.
  2. Во втором переходе будет        `found == 'assw'` и `index == 1`.
  3. В третьем переходе будет          `found == 'ords'` и `index == 2`.
  4. В четвёртом переходе будет `found == 'trin'` и `index == 3`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!! Теперь то стало понятно) Спасибо ещё раз за такие развернутые ответы)